# UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16>.allocate(capacity: totalPixels) is returning 0 in swift 3

Tags: swift, uiimage, unsafemutablepointer

hello i have the following code:

```
totalPixels = imageHeight * imageWidth
regionsData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16>.allocate(capacity: totalPixels)
let pixelColor = regionsData.advanced(by: (pixelY * imageWidth) + pixelX).pointee
```

where pixelColor is returning 0, this is supposed to color parts of an image when i tap on the screen, but for some reason it is not working, and of course i think the reason is because pixelColor = 0
and note that the other values are not 0 (totalPixels, pixelY, pixelX, ...)
any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are allocating a *new* memory buffer — thank god there's nothing in there already ;)

Comment: i didn't get that, what did u mean? because this code was working perfectly until i decided to get the pictures i am coloring from the server instead of locally, could it be the size of the pictures i am using?

Comment: @PauloMattos is saying that regionsData is a new empty buffer. pixelColor is zero because there is nothing in there

Comment: i know what it means i just dont know why, there is a picture and i am tapping on it as i am supposed to